# Align items to center doesn´t work on the img element when I add a link around the img tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, flexbox

This is my dinamically generated product, which items in column are vertically aligned with flexbox. This works fine in the example below, hovewer when I add lightbox( a tag around the img tag) to it the img tag gets pushed to the left margin of the div. It´s not center aligned with the rest of the elements anymore. Could you tell me why does this happen and how to fix it?

Here works:

```
  // DISPLAY PRODUCTS for USER / PUBLIC dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML
  function showProduct() {
      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">'  + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" class="lblProductImage" alt="product">' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
      }

  }
```

Here is the problem:

```
// DISPLAY PRODUCTS for USER / PUBLIC dinamically using a loop and then INSERT into HTML

function showProduct() {

      lblProductList.innerHTML = "";

      for ( var i = 0; i < ajProductDataFromServer.length; i++ ) {

          var lblProduct = '<div class ="lblProduct">' + '<a href="#' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '" width="85%" class="lblProductImage" alt="product">' + '</a>' + '<a href="#_" class="lightbox" id="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '<img src="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].image + '">' + '</a>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductName">' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].name + '</h3>' + '<h3 class ="lblProductPrice">' + 'Price:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].price + '<h3 class ="lblProductQuantity">' + 'Quantity:' + ' ' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].quantity + '</h3>' + '<button class="btnBuyProduct" data-productId="' + ajProductDataFromServer[i].id + '" >' + 'BUY PRODUCT' + '</button>' + '</div>';

          lblProductList.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', lblProduct );
      }

  }
```

My CSS:

```
.lblProduct {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 30vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid lightgrey;
}
```

The CSS for the lightbox, if something might interfere:

```
.lightbox {
    /** Default lightbox to hidden */
    display: none;

    /** Position and style */
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.lightbox img {
    /** Pad the lightbox image */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 90%;
    margin-top: 3%;
}

.lightbox:target {
    /** Remove default browser outline */
    outline: none;

    /** Unhide lightbox **/
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Please include the generated HTML of the for the elements that are causing the problem, so that we can actually see where the problem might lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Chrome's dev-tools to see what was wrong and it for some reason show that the anchor fills the width of the `lblProduct`.

I guess, as it all being added using script, it set something I can't see.

Still, and as the `img` render as an inline element, setting `text-align: center` on its parent will center it horizontally, so by adding this rule it fixes the issue.

```
.lblProduct a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: it doesn´t work this way, probably you misunterstood me. The lightbox has nothing to do with the .lblProduct in the way as the lightbox it opens up a new image. And the styling of the lightbox is for that img, and I need to align to the center  the div containing initial view of the image + other info about the product  before opening the lightbox. That´s what gets distorted.

Comment: yeah this can be a bit confusing without seeing it as is a layout question.  There are no  other rules for the anchor. The lightbox works with only the CSS written above.

Comment: @codeDragon Deleted my previous comment by mistake. To actually be able to give a proper answer we would need a working code snippet reproducing the issue you encounter.

Comment: @codeDragon First, that webpage has the image centered, second, you are supposed to add a _minimal working code snippet within the question_, not as an external link, as nobody want to parse through a full website's code.

Comment: The image is not centered that I am sure of, look at the border around it that tells you. Sorry I did not know about that.

Comment: @codeDragon This is how it looks for me, so how is that not centered? https://i.stack.imgur.com/rriK5.jpg

Comment: as I mentioned before not in the lightbox but before opening that relative to its border. All the images in the lblProduct. Just the normal display of all the images when u land on the page.

Comment: @codeDragon Yes, I misunderstood again :) ... being tired I guess, still, found a fix and updated my answer

Comment: how awesome. :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Target enclosing div tag and make that align to center. Or instead of using the anchor tag add an event listener of click to the `<img>` itself.